# Using both props.children and default Parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-props

I'm facing a problem using default parameters in a functional component (React.js v17.0.2).
I have the component above, which receives specific parameters with a default value. How can I make this component able to still receiving props like when using *MyComponent(props){...}* ?
More specific, how can I make this component able to receive props.children?

```
export default function Box({style = "red-box"}, {size="xl"} ) {
console.log(props)
return (
    <div className={`${style} ${size}`}>
        {props.children} <----
    </div>
)}
```

Hope the idea is clear. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this suffice?

```
export default function Box({children, size="xl", style="red-box"}) {
return (
    <div className={`${style} ${size}`}>
        {children}
    </div>
)}
```

Comment: Actually it does! Also I noticed you can pass "...props" as a parameter and being able to use any other props using props dot "props." like this
`code
export default function Box({ size="xl", style="red-box", ...props}) {
return (
    <div className={`${style} ${size}`}>
        {children}
    </div>
)}`

Comment: right, that is known as the rest operator, you can read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters